# Passing data from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php variable called `$VrHistorySlider`, defined like this:

```php
$VrHistorySlider.='<table border="0"><tr><td>(oldest)</td><td style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px ;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="note-slider-'.$VrNoteId.'" style="width:'.$VrSliderWidth.'px;background: url(\''.$VrSliderBGImg.'\') repeat-x ;" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>(latest)</td></tr></table>';
```

Now I want to store it in a JavaScript variable. I tried this:

```
var slidercontent = <?= $VrHistorySlider ?>;
```

but it gives me this error:

> unknown XML entity `nbsp`
>   `<parent xmlns=""><table border="0"><tr...td>(latest)</td></tr></table></parent>`

If not that, then how do I assign this `$VrHistorySlider` to the JavaScript variable `slidercontent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var slidercontent = <?php echo json_encode($VrHistorySlider); ?>;
```

Comment: @ icktoofay:I have used json_encode().So when I use this variable in php script is it required to convert this variable using json_decode to get the original value????I have used json_decode() but it returns blank..

Comment: @user822418: `json_encode` returns the encoded value; it does not modify the value you pass to it. (additionally, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by ticking the hollow check mark next to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

All you need are quotation marks around the php variable, as when you try and assign it like that it is putting the raw code onto the page rather than making it a string.

You also need to escape the quotation marks in the string as otherwise they will make it seem as if the string is ending and it won't work.

So it should look like:

```
var slidercontent = "<?=addslashes($VrHistorySlider)?>";
```

Comment: `addslashes` doesn't seem to escape any Unicode characters, although I don't know how much of a problem that is.